# Problem applying Decorator Design Pattern to JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a class named Calculation which I added two functions are addOperationToName() and sayOperation() as examples of the Decorator design pattern. However, when I test it using Jest, I got an error that 'fn is not a function'. Can someone help me?

Calculation.js

```
class Calculation {
constructor(a, b, op) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.op = op;
}

static Create(a, b, op){
    return new Calculation(a, b, op);
}

 GetResults() {
    return this.op(this.a,this.b)
}

addOperationToName(fn){
    return function(name){
        const operation = name + ' is a operation';
        fn(operation);
    }
}

sayOperation(name){
    console.log(name);
}
}
module.exports = Calculation;
```

Calculation.test.js

```
const Calculation = require('../src/models/Calculation');

test('Test say name for Product operation', () => {
let op = Product;
let calculation = new Calculation(1,2,op);
let sayTest = calculation.addOperationToName(calculation.sayOperation());
expect(sayTest('Multiply')).toBe('Multiply is an operation');
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to reference ```calculation.sayOperation```? In the scope of the Jest test, `sayOperation` has not been declared which is why you are getting that error.

Comment: I did change it to calculation.sayOperation and there is an error said undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to pass a function to `addOperationToName`, right now you are returning the *result* of a function - just change `calculation.addOperationToName(calculation.sayOperation());` to `calculation.addOperationToName(calculation.sayOperation);`

```js
class Calculation {
    constructor(a, b, op) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.op = op;
    }

    static Create(a, b, op){
        return new Calculation(a, b, op);
    }

     GetResults() {
        return this.op(this.a,this.b)
    }

    addOperationToName(fn){
        return function(name){
            const operation = name + ' is a operation';
            return fn(operation);
        }
    }

    sayOperation(name){
        console.log(name);
        return name;
    }
}

let calculation = new Calculation(1,2,null);
let sayTest = calculation.addOperationToName(calculation.sayOperation);
console.log(sayTest('Multiply') === 'Multiply is a operation')
```

Comment: I did change it but there is an error said undefined

Comment: see edit - you need to return the results of `addOperationToName` and of `sayOperation`, previously it was just `console.log`-ing it